# Parsing json data with inconsistent keys

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

How can i parse below json data with inconsistent keys inside data object?Can i create a model class with such json data?It would have been simple if each array in data object has same key.But with different key how should i proceed?Can i use gson with this?

Note-The key values 2016 and 2015 are not fixed and are random .There can be more arrays inside data object with random key values.

```
{
  "responseCode": 200,
  "responseMessage": "Operation succeeded successfully",
  "data": {
    "2016": [
      [
        {
          "key": "Id",
          "value": "101_202704916"
        },
        {
          "key": "amount",
          "value": "1.48"
        },
        {
          "key": "Type",
          "value": "gchgch"
        }
      ],
      [
          {
          "key": "Id",
          "value": "101_202704916"
        },
        {
          "key": "amount",
          "value": "1.48"
        },
        {
          "key": "Type",
          "value": "gchgch"
        }
      ]
      ],
      "2015": [
      [
         {
          "key": "Id",
          "value": "101_202704916"
        },
        {
          "key": "amount",
          "value": "1.48"
        },
        {
          "key": "Type",
          "value": "gchgch"
        }

      ],
      [
          {
          "key": "Id",
          "value": "101_202704916"
        },
        {
          "key": "amount",
          "value": "1.48"
        },
        {
          "key": "Type",
          "value": "gchgch"
        }

      ]
      ]
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you can do something like that with `gson`. I think what you're looking for is `LinkedTreeMap`. So try something along the lines of:

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("data")
private LinkedTreeMap<String, ArrayList<LinkedTreeMap<String, String>>> mT1;
```

I'm not entirely sure if that's the right amount of wrapping lists, so adjust according to your JSON model. But I've used `LinkedTreeMap` for something similar before and it works like magic.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
public class KeyModel {
    @SerializedName("key")
    private String key;
    @SerializedName("value")
    private String value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}



public class DataModel {
    @SerializedName("2016")
    private List<List<KeyModel>> list2016;
    @SerializedName("2015")
    private List<List<KeyModel>> list2015;

    public List<List<KeyModel>> getList2016() {
        return list2016;
    }

    public void setList2016(List<List<KeyModel>> list2016) {
        this.list2016 = list2016;
    }

    public List<List<KeyModel>> getList2015() {
        return list2015;
    }

    public void setList2015(List<List<KeyModel>> list2015) {
        this.list2015 = list2015;
    }
}

public class ResponseModel {
    @SerializedName("responseCode")
    private int responseCode;
    @SerializedName("responseMessage")
    private String responseMessage;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private DataModel data;

    public int getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public void setResponseCode(int responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    public String getResponseMessage() {
        return responseMessage;
    }

    public void setResponseMessage(String responseMessage) {
        this.responseMessage = responseMessage;
    }

    public DataModel getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(DataModel data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: The key values 2016 and 2015 are not fixed and are random .There can be more arraylist inside data object with random key values.How can i handle this?

Comment: Data is an object and there are two arrays inside that..are u sure List<List<List<KeyModel>>> data; will work ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know there is a the keys follows some sequence, you can apply the logic 
and you can use the following method as some kind of check,

```
    boolean has(String keyName)
```

- return true,if JsonObject has value mapped to keyName.